# What the does Quran say about birds in general and/or specific bird species?

Tags: quran, tafseer, hudud

I am aware that the [Hudhud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudhud_(mythology)) is considered sacred, but I am wondering if there are any other species mentioned, such as seagulls, or if the Quran mandates specific behavior towards birds in general. Can birds be considered haraam/halal for instance? Is there a particular punishment for harming or capturing a Hudhud?